# CreateView неправильно работает с загрузкой файла, почему?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно сохранить файл через форму, делаю так:

```
models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='images')

forms.py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

views.py
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

Например, если я выбрал файл и не заполнил title, то перезагружается страница, над title пишется, что поле обязательное, а выбранный файл не отображается, я заполняю тайтл и не выбираю заново файл, перезагружается страница и пишется, что файл не выбран, но если заново выберу файл, то сохранится...

Мне интересно, это CreateView некорректно работает с файлами или я что-то делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно, файловые поля в браузерах не сохраняют загруженный файл из соображений безопасности. Если нужно сохранять, используйте специальный виджет вроде https://github.com/un1t/django-file-resubmit